# Using same inputs for each function in c++

Tags: c++

Okay, so I have little program I made, which asks user for inputs, and then adds, subtracts and etc. But somehow, it doesn't work right. It must use x and y inputs for each function, but it seems like it uses outputs from previous instead.

Here's a code:

Main:

```
//  ========================================================================
//  NumberProject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//  ========================================================================

//  ==================
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <iostream>
//  ==================

//  ================
//  Class Inclusions
//  ==================
   #include "Number.h"
//  ==================

//  ====================
    using namespace std;
//  ====================

    void Banner();

//  =============
    int main( ) {

//      ================================
//      Variable and Object Declarations
//      ============
        char answer;
        bool goAgain = true;

        int  integerValue;

        Number x;
        Number y;

        Banner();

//      =========
//      User loop
//      ===================
        while ( goAgain ) {

            cout << "Enter an integer:  ";
            cin >> integerValue;
            x.Set( integerValue );

            cout << "Enter an integer:  ";
            cin >> integerValue;
            y.Set( integerValue );
            cout << endl;

//          Addition

            x.Add( y );
            cout << "Addition: ";
            x.Output( );

//          Subtraction

            x.Subtract( y );
            cout << "Subtraction: ";
            x.Output( );

//          Multiplication

            x.Multiply( y );
            cout << "Multiplication: ";
            x.Output( );

//          Division

            x.Divide( y );
            cout << "Division: ";
            x.Output( );

//          ===========================
//          User loop termination code.
//          ====================================================
            cout << "Would you like go again continue? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;

            if ( answer == 'n' )
                goAgain = false;
//          ====================

        } // while
//      ==========

        return 0;

    } // Function main( )

//  =====================

        void Banner() {

            cout << "====================================" << endl;
            cout << "   Welcome to the Number Project    " << endl;
            cout << "====================================" << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }

// ================================================================
```

Number.cpp:

```
//  ==================
   #include "StdAfx.h"
   #include "math.h"     // Needed for sqrt and pow.
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>
//  ==================

//  ================
//  Class Inclusions
//  ==================
   #include "Number.h"
//  ==================

//  ====================
    using namespace std;
//  ====================

        Number::Number( void ) {

            number = 0;
        }

        Number::Number( int integerValue ) {

            number = integerValue;

        }

        Number::~Number( void ) {

        }

        int Number::Get( ) {

            return number;

        }

        void Number::Set( int integerValue ) {

            number = integerValue;

        }

        void Number::Output( ) {

            cout << number << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }


        void Number::Add( Number otherNumber ) {

            number = number + otherNumber.Get();

        }

        void Number::Subtract( Number otherNumber ) {

            number = number - otherNumber.Get();


        }

        void Number::Multiply( Number otherNumber ) {

            number = number * otherNumber.Get();

        }

        void Number::Divide( Number otherNumber ) {

            number = number / otherNumber.Get();

        }

    // =================================================
```

Number.h:

```
//  ===========
   #pragma once
//  ===========

//  ==============
    class Number {

        public:

//          ============
//          Constructors
//          ===============
            Number( void );
            Number( int );
//          ==============

//          ==========
//          Destructor
//          ===============
           ~Number( void );
            int  Number::Get( );       // Accessor
            void Number::Set( int );   // Mutator
            void Number::Output();
            void Number::Add( Number );
            void Number::Subtract( Number );
            void Number::Multiply( Number );
            void Number::Divide( Number );
//          ===========================

        private:

            int number;
    };
```

Example output:

```
==================================== Welcome to the Number Project ===================================  
Enter an integer: 2 Enter an integer: 3 Addition: 5 Subtraction: 2 Multiplication: 6 Division: 2
Would you like go again continue? (y/n)
```

Please help?

Comment: Can you give an example of actual inputs, actual outputs, and expected outputs?

Comment: Sure:

====================================
   Welcome to the Number Project
====================================

Enter an integer:  2
Enter an integer:  3

Addition: 5

Subtraction: 2

Multiplication: 6

Division: 2

Would you like go again continue? (y/n)

@nhgrif

Comment: So, `Subtraction` should result in `-1`?

Comment: Obviously yes. @nhgrif

Comment: If your question has been answered, you should consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: No, it really didn't. I need to have this x.Add(); and etc. in my main. But thanks for your help! @nhgrif

Comment: Then mark thermite's answer as accepted?  While my solution is probably more correct and more readable and better from an OOP perspective, @thermite has explained exactly how to do it using `x.Add(y)` as you're already calling it in main.

Comment: His option didn't work either :o @nhgrif

Answer (score 0):

You should move your math functions outside of the class (but remain in the `.h` and `.cpp` files).  I'll show you what addition should look like, and you should be able to figure out the rest.

```
Number addNumbers(Number a, Number b)
{
    return Number(a.Get()+b.Get());
}
```

Then to call this in main, you'll do something like this:

```
Number result;
result = addNumbers(x, y);
```

This leaves the contents of `x` and `y` unmodified and gives you a new object, `result`, which contains the sum.  Rinse and repeat for your other math functions.

To clarify "moving it outside of the class", in your `.h`, you have this:

```
class Number {
    //stuff
};
```

Included in `"//stuff"` is your math functions.  So change your `.h` to look like this:

```
class Number {
    //stuff minus math functions
};

Number addNumbers(Number a, Number b);
Number subtractNumbers(Number a, Number b);
//etc.
```

From an organizational standpoint, these belong in the same file as your `Number` class because they take `Number`s as arguments and return a `Number`, but they don't operate on an instance of the `Number` class, and as such, they work much better as free functions like this.

Comment: What do you mean by moving my math function outside of the class?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
    void Number::Add( Number otherNumber ) {

        number = number + otherNumber.Get();

    }
```

by calling x.add(y) you are actually modifying the number value of x. You have two options. like nhgrif suggested you could have separate addNumbers function that isn't part of the class and does as he suggests or you could do something like

```
    Number Number::Add( Number otherNumber ) {

        return Number( number + otherNumber.Get());
    }
```

and use it the same way that he suggested to use addNumbers

Comment: While this is a perfectly valid approach, I'm not a fan of this method at all.  When I call `x.Add(y)`, the expectation is that I'm modifying `x`.  Your solution doesn't modify `x` (or `y`) and does exactly what the original poster wants, but the readability suffers.  In his original question, he's using `x.Add(y)` and I assumed that this meant that `x`'s new value should be increased by the value of `y`.

Comment: I tend to agree with you that x.add(y) should modify the value of x, based on the comment he made about expected input and output it seemed reasonable to do it this way.

Comment: Your way not really working. Can you please assist me with more help please? @thermite

Comment: @berdyev You'll have to show your attempt at implementing his solution.

Comment: @berdyev how did you attempt to implement it?

Comment: I just replaced your adding function with my, which I don't think was a right idea. @thermite